# How can i use the returned value from "if statement " to use it in other calculation?

Tags: c, if-statement

I have this code which take the inputs from user and in "Category"input it check it in if statement and return a variable  call "pay_hour" with a value assigned to it .i need to use "pay_hour"value in other calculation ;

```
     if (strncmp(category,"A1",2)== 0){return pay_hour=5;}
else if (strncmp(category,"A2",2)== 0){return pay_hour=7;}
else if (strncmp(category,"M1",2)== 0){return pay_hour=10;}
else if (strncmp(category,"M2",2)== 0){return pay_hour=15;}
else if (strncmp(category,"BB",2)== 0){return pay_hour=20;}

pay=50*pay_hour;

printf("pay= %.2f,pay);

getchar();
}
```

Comment: `return` exits from the function. Don't use it if you want to stay in the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `return` if you want to use the variable in further calculations. Just assign the variable.

```
if (strncmp(category,"A1",2)== 0){pay_hour=5;}
else if (strncmp(category,"A2",2)== 0){pay_hour=7;}
else if (strncmp(category,"M1",2)== 0){pay_hour=10;}
else if (strncmp(category,"M2",2)== 0){pay_hour=15;}
else if (strncmp(category,"BB",2)== 0){pay_hour=20;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are misusing return statement. `return` means that to terminat the execution of current function and return control to the calling function, or the operating system if your are returning from the `main` function.

See this for more detailed explanation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k68ktdwf.aspx

In your case, simpily assign value to `pay_hour` without `return`.

Comment: @KerrekSB Correct that